# How to save the form values in magento2 controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, registration

How to save new attributes values in the Magento2 controller from registration form.

Please, Anyone guide me how to save value?

Comment: Did you add new field in registration form using phtml ?

Comment: Yes I'm using new phtml file